# TWTRTimeLineViewController Hides Tab Bar Item Image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, twitter-fabric

I'm dealing with an issue and would be glad if someone could help:

Background:
I'm trying to develop an iOS app using swift that has a section which draws a user's timeline using Twitter Fabric.

Issue: 
I'm having an issue with the tab bar control I've used and have finally zeroed down to the Fabric SDK as the culprit (maybe I'm wrong) - I tried creating a fresh project and the moment you use the TWTRTimeLineViewController, the tab bar image goes away, even the title is not seen.

My layout is like this:

Tab Bar Control (2 tabs)

- TableViewController: has TWTRTimeLineViewController as the viewController to get a Twitter timeline
- Navigation View Controller - has a TableViewController that draws YouTube Channels

The problem is that (see Image attached - bottom right hand side) - the tab bar item - containing the twitter feed never displays its image or title... irrespective of it being selected or not.

PS: Not allowed to post an image as this is my first post. I've also written a query here: https://twittercommunity.com/t/twtrtimelineviewcontroller-hides-tab-bar-item-image/45178

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me now was that I added a navigationController between the tabController and tableViewController. Strange workaround, but it did. I think the problem was that the twitter feeds would overlap the constraints of the tab bar controller and there needed to be a way to override that in code. The navigation controller perhaps restricts that.

Comment: That works but the timeline is under the navigationBar that comes with the UINavigationController and no barButtonItems show nor does the title of the navigationBar appear.

Answer (score 0):

(NOTE: I don't have enough reputation to comment)

I'm experiencing the exact same issue. Using TWTRTimeLineViewController in one of my tabs causes that one icon to disappear (the other 4 icons remain visible). I should also note that the text disappears along with the icon.

EDIT: I'm running Xcode 7 Beta 3.

EDIT 2: I am still using TWTRTimeLineViewController, but the icon is now visible! I'm not entirely sure what I changed though unfortunately...